# MySQL select specific year or year month rows that have yyyy-mm-dd as the date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ok, Im sure this is simple and its just evading me at the moment. But Im searching and I can't find it either, maybe I don't know what Im searching for term wise. Anyway.

I have a table, with rows of posts, and within those rows is a column thats in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, might be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` either way. I'm Trying to build a query that will let me select either just the entries in a specific year, or specific month of a given year. But since the formats are what they are, Im confusing myself, I know theres a way to format the dates in the query so they will be easy to compare against. But I cant think of it.

My thought process is seriously flawed currently. at the moment on how to handle that.

Note I am using Codeigniter and its ORM as well

Comment: what is the data type of row? is it varchar? date? or datetime?

Answer (score 6):

You could try this code

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime_column, '%Y') AS year
```

or to fetch year specific record

```
 YEAR(datetime_column)='2012'
```

to fetch month specific record

```
 MONTH(datetime_column)='11'
```

Comment: Well even what I was thinking was way off from that. Wow, so yes, thank you. Now all I need to do is work that into CodeIgniters active record, and Ill be golden.